# google optimize - installation issue

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

Is there a way to specify what datalayer Google Optimize will use?

I have two datalayers and i would like to specify which one will be used for google optimize. Google Optimize by default is using my first one that is not array object and that's why the installation fails. GA tag is visible in tag assistant, but google optimize tag is not. If i change first one to be javascript array object both tags are loaded properly.

*Please take a look at code snippet below.*

P.S. Google optimize code snippet is added directly to page, not via GTM.

Thank you in advance!

```html
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var dataLayer = {}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var googleAnalyticsDataLayer = []
</script>
    
<script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXX', 'auto');
        ga('require', 'GTM-XXX');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
  
</script>

</head>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If there is datalayer defined like this: 
"<script type="text/javascript">
        var dataLayer = {}
    </script>"
 google optimize will not be installed correctly.

Comment: I am not able to change that one to array since it is used for another analytics.